# Query builder isn't execute where = on another column

Tags: laravel

Sorry, my question title isn't very clear but I couldn't figure a way to word this question.

I have the following query builder code.

```
return self::select(DB::raw('sum(user_points.points) AS points, users.id AS user_id, users.username, users.avatar, users.firstname, users.lastname'))
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_points.user_id')
            $query->where('user_points.artist_id', 0)->orWhere('user_points.artist_id', 'users.favourite_artist_id');
            })
            ->where('user_points.created_at', '>=', $startDate)
            ->where('user_points.created_at', '<=', $endDate)
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->orderBy('points', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')
            ->simplePaginate(100);
```

It runs ok but is ignore the inner where query, specifically it's ignoring part of this;

```
$query->where('user_points.artist_id', 0)->orWhere('user_points.artist_id', 'users.favourite_artist_id');
                })
```

It's matching 'user_points.artist_id = 0', but it's not matching the 'user_points.artist_id = users.favourite_artist_id', presumable it's got something to do with the way it's handling the bindings? But I can't seem to find a way to get it to work.

The complete query should end up like this;

```
SELECT SUM(user_points.points) AS points, users.id AS user_id, users.username, users.avatar, users.firstname, users.lastname
            FROM user_points
            INNER JOIN users ON users.id = user_points.user_id
            WHERE (user_points.artist_id = 0 OR user_points.artist_id = users.favourite_artist_id)
              AND user_points.created_at >= '$startDate' AND user_points.created_at <= '$endDate'
            GROUP BY user_id
            ORDER BY points DESC, user_id ASC
```

I updated the query builder code to this.

```
return self::select(DB::raw('sum(user_points.points) AS points, users.id AS user_id, users.username, users.avatar, users.firstname, users.lastname'))
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_points.user_id')
            ->where(function($query) {
                    $query->Where('user_points.artist_id', 0)->orWhere(DB::raw('user_points.artist_id = users.favourite_artist_id'));
            })
            ->where('user_points.created_at', '>=', $startDate)
            ->where('user_points.created_at', '<=', $endDate)
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->orderBy('points', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')
            ->simplePaginate(100);
```

That didn't work as the final query ended up looking like this.

```
select sum(user_points.points) AS points, users.id AS user_id, users.username, users.avatar, users.firstname, users.lastname 
from `user_points` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `user_points`.`user_id` where (`user_points`.`artist_id` = ? or user_points.artist_id = users.favourite_artist_id is null) 
and `user_points`.`created_at` >= ? 
and `user_points`.`created_at` <= ? 
group by `users`.`id` 
order by `points` desc, `user_id` asc
```

Comment: Did you try 

`$query->where(function($query) {
 $query->orWhere('user_points.artist_id', 0)
    ->orWhere('user_points.artist_id', 'users.favourite_artist_id');
})`

Comment: Yes I've tried that but the results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the second where (or) as a raw query. The where method will add the second column as a value so you are actually trying the following:

```
user_points.artist_id = 'users.favourite_artist_id'
```

Try the following:

```
whereRaw("user_points.artist_id = users.favourite_artist_id")
```

Comment: Could you give me an example, I've tried adding the second orWhere as a raw query, but then the final query is incorrect.